# Get backend instance from react-dnd

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd, react-big-calendar

I'm attempting to use `react-dnd` and `react-big-calendar` with drag-n-drop support (using `react-dnd` under the hood as well) in an app together. However, if I initiate them separately, I get an error:

`Uncaught Error: Cannot have two HTML5 backends at the same time.`

Here's the code:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {DragDropContext} from 'react-dnd'
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend'
import Calendar from './Calendar'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return {
      <div>
        ...
        <Calendar />
      </div>
    }
  }
}

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(App)
```

**Calendar.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar'
import withDragAndDrop from 'react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop'

const Calendar = withDragAndDrop(BigCalendar)
...
```

`react-big-calendar` documentation [mentions](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar/blob/master/src/addons/dragAndDrop/withDragAndDrop.js) that the `withDragAndDrop()` function can accept a backend as a second argument, meaning, in theory, I should be able to retrieve the backend instance that I have already set for `react-dnd` and pass it as an argument. However, I'm not sure how I retrieve the backend instance.

`react-dnd` [documentation for `DragDropContext`](http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drag-drop-context.html) mentions an instance method `getManager()` which should help me retrieve the backend (`getManager().getBackend()`). However, the key here is *instance* method. How do I get the instance of `DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(App)` from my `Calendar.js` file?